# Summing R Matrix ignoring NA's

Tags: r, matrix, sum, dataframe

I have the following claim counts data (triangular) by limits:

```
claims=matrix(c(2019,690,712,NA,773,574,NA,NA,232),nrow=3, byrow=T)
```

What would be the most elegant way to do the following simple things resembling Excel's `sumif()`:

1. put the matrix into `as.data.frame()` with column names: "100k", "250k", "500k"
2. sum all numbers except first row; (in this case summing 773,574, and 232). I am looking for a neat reference so I can easily generalize the notation to larger claim triangles.

Sum all numbers, ignoring the NA's. `sum(claims, na.rm = T)` - Thanks for Gregor's suggestion.
*I played around with the package `ChainLadder` a bit and enjoyed how it handles triangular data, especially in plotting and calculating link ratios. I wonder more generally if basic R suffices in doing some quick and dirty `sumif()` or pairwise link ratio kind of calculations? This would be a bonus for me if anyone out there could dispense some words of wisdom.

Thank you!

Comment: Look at `?sum`, notice that you can set `na.rm = T`.

Comment: @Actuary see edits for some "sumif" examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
claims=matrix(c(2019,690,712,NA,773,574,NA,NA,232),nrow=3, byrow=T) 
claims.df = as.data.frame(claims)
names(claims.df) <- c("100k", "250k", "500k")
# This isn't the best idea because standard column names don't start with numbers
# If you go non-standard, you'll have to always quote them, that is
claims.df$100k   # doesn't work
claims.df$`100k` # works    

# sum everything
sum(claims, na.rm = T)

# sum everything except for first row
sum(claims[-1, ], na.rm = T)
```

It's much easier to give specific advice to specific questions than general advice. As to " I wonder more generally if basic R suffices in doing some quick and dirty `sumif()` or pairwise link ratio kind of calculations?", at least as to the `sumif` comment, I'm reminded of `fortunes::fortune(286)`

> ...this is kind of like asking "will your Land Rover make it up my driveway?", but I'll assume the question was asked in all seriousness.

`sum` adds up whatever numbers you give it. Subsetting based on logicals so simple that there is no need for a separate `sumif` function. Say you have `x = rnorm(100)`, `y = runif(100)`.

```
# sum x if x > 0
sum(x[x > 0])

# sum x if y < 0.5
sum(x[y < 0.5])

# sum x if x > 0 and y < 0.5
sum(x[x > 0 & y < 0.5])

# sum every other x
sum(x[c(T, F)]

# sum all but the first 10 and last 10 x
sum(x[-c(1:10, 91:100)]
```

I don't know what a pairwise link ratio is, but I'm willing to bet base R can handle it easily.

Comment: really appreciate the writeup, I definitely learned from your examples. In them, you used x, y - are they data frame names? I assume example 3 is used in a situation like: `x=matrix(sample(9),nrow=3);y=matrix(sample(9),nrow=3);sum(x[x>5&y>3])`? In which case here `y` almost works likes a logic indicator matrix of sort, please let me know if this is what your example means?

Comment: In my examples `x` and `y` are just vectors, which could be rows or columns of matrices, or columns of data frames. (After defining `x` run `is(x)` to see lots of details on what it is.) Yes, when you use boolean operators, you are converting a vector to a logical indicator. In my examples, you can run just what is *inside* the square brackets to see that, e.g.: `x > 0`, `y  < 0.5`, `x > 0 & y < 0.5`. The fourth example illustrates "recycling", the `T, F` pattern is recycled for the entire length of `x`.